# Remove Space Between Bars in Bar Chart in Google Visualization API

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have a single data series and need the bars stacked right next to each other. What Google Visualization API call / property would help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set the `bar.groupWidth` option.  You can either set it as an integer (number of pixels for the group to take up) or as a percent of the available space.  In your case, I suggest using the percent:

```
bar: {
    groupWidth: '100%'
}
```

That will remove all space from between adjacent bars.